# Проблемы в верстке

Tags: html5, css3, вёрстка

Всем привет! Я новичок в верстке с большой буквы Н. Понятное дело возникли проблемы. Исходный код:

```
.page-s { 
    max-width:1400px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.block { 
    max-width: 940px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
    
.contact {
      width: 45%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10%;
      padding-top: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden
    }

    .contact img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    .contact h2 {
      font-size: 1.000em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
    }

    .contact h3 {
      font-size: 0.875em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .social li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .contact-1 {
      width: 45%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-top: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden
    }

    .contact-1 img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    .contact-1 h2 {
      font-size: 1.000em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
    }

    .contact-1 h3 {
      font-size: 0.875em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .social-1 li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .social {
      padding: 20px 0 20px 0
    }

    .p {
      font-size: 0.875em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      display: block;
      padding-top: 200px;
      text-align: center
    }
    <div class="page-s">
      <div class="block">
        <h1>Our magazine team</h1>
        <h2>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure.</h2>
        <div class="contact-1">
          <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="avatar">
          <h2>Kimberly Thompson</h2>
          <h3>Marketer</h3>
          <ul class="social">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/printerest.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="avatar">
          <h2>Rico Massino</h2>
          <h3>Coder</h3>
          <ul class="social">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/printerest.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <p class="p">Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt proin iaculis</p>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Но не работает padding-top для абзаца. Назначается ширина и высота в 940*413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему ты думаешь что не работает? Увеличиваю до 400 и видно что работает

```
 padding-top: 400px;
```

Он у тебя относительно верхнего элемента div.

```
<div class="page-s">
  <div class="block">
```

Если хочешь то можешь `<p class="p">` переместить выше `<div class="page-s">` (после `</div>`). И тогда он будет относительно последнего элемента  а не первого.

```css
.page-s { 
    max-width:1400px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    background-color: #f7f7f7
}

.block { 
    max-width: 940px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
    
.contact {
      width: 45%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10%;
      padding-top: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden
    }

    .contact img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    .contact h2 {
      font-size: 1.000em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
    }

    .contact h3 {
      font-size: 0.875em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .social li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .contact-1 {
      width: 45%;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-top: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden
    }

    .contact-1 img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    .contact-1 h2 {
      font-size: 1.000em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
    }

    .contact-1 h3 {
      font-size: 0.875em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .social-1 li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .social {
      padding: 20px 0 20px 0
    }

    .p {
      font-size: 0.875em;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      display: block;
      padding-top: 400px;
      text-align: center
    }
```

```html
    <div class="page-s">
      <div class="block">
        <h1>Our magazine team</h1>
        <h2>Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure.</h2>
        <div class="contact-1">
          <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="avatar">
          <h2>Kimberly Thompson</h2>
          <h3>Marketer</h3>
          <ul class="social">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/printerest.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          <img src="images/avatar.png" alt="avatar">
          <h2>Rico Massino</h2>
          <h3>Coder</h3>
          <ul class="social">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><img src="images/printerest.png" alt="facebook"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <p class="p">Proin iaculis purus consequat sem cure digni ssim donec porttitora entum suscipit aenean rhoncus posuere odio in tincidunt proin iaculis</p>

      </div>
    </div>
```